# What is the notion of sub-IP?

Tags: integrated-circuit

all

I am CS engineer, mainly dealing with massive IP(Intellectual Property) data using Helix Perforce. Hence, sometimes I have faced with difficulties about semiconductor jargon.

What is "Sub-IP"? What is the difference between general IP and sub-IP?

Answer (score 1):

It defines the Subordinate IP when there is a hierarchy or dependencies to the parent IP.

https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_crm70/7.0.0.18/en-US/8e/206a62137b4df19172bb63031f7150/frameset.htm

For example some libraries may be a sub-IP to a complex ASIC with a parent IP.

Comment: +1 Concise, on-topic, answer. Hope I didn't disappoint you, Tony.

Comment: Gracias senõr @ElliotAlderson

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks. One more question. Under what circumstance do sub-IP make conflict?

Comment: I’m not an expert on this, but it seems to me from my limited understanding of Black’s Law, that any criteria not met in a subordinate follows the same rules as the parent.  Like Distributing. entertainment media.  The Radio, TV  stations must pay a Royalty to the parent who pays their parent etc. FOR COMMERCIAL purposes. How often does it go direct from Subordinate to Owner depends how big the user is. THat is why legal IP property distribution has all the dependencies included to the direct corp. Like WIndows uses CODEC rights and all the other code licences.